# Wildfly 11 multi domain certificate SSL

Tags: wildfly

Suppose I have a few websites with different domain names, domainA.com, domainB.jp, etc. I have setup the correct virtualhosts configuration for these sites in wildfly 11.
And I am planning on buying mutlti domain SSL certificate from GoDaddy.
A Multi-domain SSL Certificate can secure your main domain + several SAN ( Subject Alternative Name) domain names in one Certificate. 
My question is that can wildfly recognize this kind of SSL certificate.

Answer (score 0):

I have just solved my problem. Wildfly 11 recognized multi domain SSL certificate file. Multi-domain SSL Certificates do not require several dedicated IP addresses for your host names.